# Reading file and check it is at the end in loop node javascript syncronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt").toString('utf-8');
var textByLine = text.split("\n")


while(!text.atEnd())
```

^ I want to do something like this where it keeps running until the end of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: fs.readFileSync, reads the whole file.  so nothing to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to iterate through the returned buffer line by line.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt").toString('utf-8');
var buffer = text.split("\n")

for (line in buffer) {
    // buffer[line] is your current line, do whatever you want with it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool package I previously used from github for my work. Hope it will work for you also here. See at here https://github.com/nacholibre/node-readlines

```
var lineByLine = require('n-readlines');
var liner = new lineByLine('./mytext.txt');

var line;
var lineNumber = 0;
while (line = liner.next()) {
    console.log('Line ' + lineNumber);
    lineNumber++;
}

console.log('end of line reached');
```

Comment: This is good thanks, but how can I split the line eg var splitLine = liner.split(','); so I can retrieve the index of the line and store it into an object?